# boost::stacktrace prints addresses

Tags: c++, bash, boost, stack-trace

I can compile all examples of boost:stacktrace. Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CXX=~/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++
export BOOST_INCLUDE=$HOME/x-libs/$($CXX -dumpmachine)/include
export BOOST_LIB=$HOME/x-libs/$($CXX -dumpmachine)/lib
export BOOST_SUFFIX="mt-d"
(ls $BOOST_LIB/*$BOOST_SUFFIX.a | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 -n 1 basename | while read A; do B=-l$(echo $A | sed -e 's/^lib//' | sed -e 's/\.a//'); echo $B; done;) | tr "\n" " " > $BOOST_LIB/list_boost.txt
export BOOST_LIBS="cat $BOOST_LIB/list_boost.txt"
export EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX=""

$CXX -w -g3 -o assert_handler-$($CXX -dumpmachine)$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX assert_handler.cpp -std=c++11 -static -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIB $(eval $BOOST_LIBS) -ldl
$CXX -w -g3 -o debug_function-$($CXX -dumpmachine)$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX debug_function.cpp -std=c++11 -static -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIB $(eval $BOOST_LIBS) -ldl
$CXX -w -g3 -o terminate_handler-$($CXX -dumpmachine)$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX terminate_handler.cpp -std=c++11 -static -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIB $(eval $BOOST_LIBS) -ldl -lrt -lpthread
$CXX -w -g3 -o throwing_st-$($CXX -dumpmachine)$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX throwing_st.cpp -std=c++11 -static -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIB $(eval $BOOST_LIBS) -ldl
$CXX -w -g3 -o trace_addresses-$($CXX -dumpmachine)$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX trace_addresses.cpp -std=c++11 -static -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIB $(eval $BOOST_LIBS)
$CXX -w -g3 -o user_config-$($CXX -dumpmachine)$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX user_config.cpp -std=c++11 -static -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIB $(eval $BOOST_LIBS) -ldl
```

The generated boost list looks like this:

```
-lboost_atomic-mt-d -lboost_chrono-mt-d -lboost_container-mt-d -lboost_context-mt-d -lboost_coroutine-mt-d -lboost_date_time-mt-d -lboost_exception-mt-d -lboost_fiber-mt-d -lboost_filesystem-mt-d -lboost_graph-mt-d -lboost_iostreams-mt-d -lboost_locale-mt-d -lboost_log-mt-d -lboost_log_setup-mt-d -lboost_math_c99f-mt-d -lboost_math_c99l-mt-d -lboost_math_c99-mt-d -lboost_math_tr1f-mt-d -lboost_math_tr1l-mt-d -lboost_math_tr1-mt-d -lboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt-d -lboost_program_options-mt-d -lboost_random-mt-d -lboost_regex-mt-d -lboost_serialization-mt-d -lboost_signals-mt-d -lboost_stacktrace_addr2line-mt-d -lboost_stacktrace_basic-mt-d -lboost_stacktrace_noop-mt-d -lboost_system-mt-d -lboost_test_exec_monitor-mt-d -lboost_thread-mt-d -lboost_timer-mt-d -lboost_type_erasure-mt-d -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt-d -lboost_wave-mt-d -lboost_wserialization-mt-d
```

If I run an example it prints pointers:

```
./assert_handler-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
Expression 'i < N' is false in function 'T& boost::array<T, N>::operator[](boost::array<T, N>::size_type) [with T = int; long unsigned int N = 5ul; boost::array<T, N>::reference = int&; boost::array<T, N>::size_type = long unsigned int]': out of range.
Backtrace:
 0# 0x00000000004019B2
 1# 0x0000000000401B39
 2# 0x0000000000400E3B
 3# 0x0000000000400E6B
 4# 0x0000000000400E44
 5# 0x0000000000400E6B
 6# 0x0000000000400E7C
 7# 0x000000000045BF2B
 8# 0x000000000045C1D1
 9# 0x0000000000400CEA
```

Have I miss something?

Comment: I haven't used it but don't you need to tell boost to lookup the symbolic info?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me now.

1. boost::stacktrace needs libbacktrace to print more than pointers
2. the compiler needs `-lbacktrace -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE`

The full line for compilation in the upper bash script example is then:

```
$CXX -w -g3 -o assert_handler-$($CXX -dumpmachine)$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX assert_handler.cpp -std=c++11 -static -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIB $(eval $BOOST_LIBS) -ldl -lbacktrace -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE
```

boost::stacktrace is new in the current Boost v1.65.1 and Debian Stretch that I use has only v1.62.0 and doesn't provide libbacktrace. So I had to download/compile these two on my own.

I cross compile for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu and i686-w64-mingw32. It works for Linux but the mingw executables print almost nothing. I will investigate that and maybe post my results later here.

Comment: It seems that boost::stacktrace [compiles](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/develop/developer/stacktrace.html) with mingw. But the [Git forum](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/issues/14) says it works with mingw64 and the mingw32 that I use has problems with this boost module.

Comment: 3 years later, I was needing the exact same solution. Thank you!